# SQL Query opetimistion and how to manage the memory while executeing query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Wrote a Sql Query, it was listed out the Table name and column name which column data was matched. it was doing search on all tables columns(table type Basic Table and column datatype was varchar or nvarchar) from the database.

**Statics:**
Database Size: 37 GB/150 GB/650 GB (have different databases) 
Tables Count: 467 (columns count :1220)

Sql Query:

```
DECLARE
    @search_string  VARCHAR(100),
     @sql_string     nvarchar(max)


SET @search_string = 'XXXXXXXX'--string only 


SELECT @sql_string='IF EXISTS (SELECT '+ISC.COLUMN_NAME+' 
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(IST.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(IST.TABLE_NAME)  
+ 'with (nolock) WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(ISC.COLUMN_NAME) + 
' ='''+@search_string+''') PRINT ''' + QUOTENAME(IST.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' 
+ QUOTENAME(IST.TABLE_NAME)  + QUOTENAME(ISC.COLUMN_NAME) + 
'''' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES IST with (nolock) 
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ISC with (nolock) 
on IST.TABLE_NAME= ISC.TABLE_NAME
WHERE IST.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
and IST.TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' 
and ISC.COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL 
and (ISC.DATA_TYPE='nvarchar' or ISC.DATA_TYPE='varchar' )


while @sql_string is not null 
begin

 EXECUTE(@sql_string)

end

Wrote same Query by using cursor as well

DECLARE
    @search_string  VARCHAR(100),
    @table_name     SYSNAME,
    @table_schema   SYSNAME,
    @column_name    SYSNAME,
    @table_type     SysName,
    @sql_string     VARCHAR(2000)    


SET @search_string = 'xxxxx@hotmail.com' -- custom/agent data

DECLARE tables_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES with (nolock) WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

OPEN tables_cur

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_schema, @table_name,@table_type

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE columns_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS with (nolock)  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema AND TABLE_NAME = @table_name AND COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL and (DATA_TYPE='nvarchar' or DATA_TYPE='varchar' )  -- Only strings have this and they always have it

    OPEN columns_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql_string = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT '+QUOTENAME(@column_name)+' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)  + 'with (nolock) WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@column_name) + ' ='''+@search_string+''') PRINT ''' + QUOTENAME(@table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ', '+ QUOTENAME(@table_type) +',' + QUOTENAME(@column_name) + ''''
        --select @sql_string
        EXECUTE(@sql_string)

        FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
    END

    CLOSE columns_cur

    DEALLOCATE columns_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_schema, @table_name, @table_type
END

CLOSE tables_cur

DEALLOCATE tables_cur
```

ISSUE:
1.it was taken too much time (around 3 hours) for executing at 37 GB Database.
2. some time facing "System.OutOfMemoryException" exception, middle of the execution.

observations:
1. its takes too much time to complete the execution.
2. web application was hanged/gets sql timeout exception at the time of Query execution at back-end.

Is there any other way to reduce the execution time?
How can i resolve exception without increase the memory?

any suggestion would be of great help please

Thanks

Comment: Have u tried using `recursive cte` effective over using `cursors`

Comment: I suggest you print out each table searched and its timing. If you search a very large table it takes a long time. Also I note that you are searching one  column at a time. If a table has 10 columns, I think you are issuing 10 SQL statements to search it. It might be quicker if you just searched once like this: `select column1,column2,column3,column4 from table where (column1 = 'search' OR column2 = 'search' OR column3 = 'search')`. And of course.... indexes help.

Comment: If you need to do this a lot then it's going to be way quicker to use a full text index. Do some reading on that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search

Comment: `System.OutOfMemoryException` is thrown by your web application (which is written in .NET), not SQL Server (which isn't). If SQL Server ran out of memory, you'd get an `SqlException` with details to that effect. If you're storing the results in a `DataTable`, be aware that that class is very inefficient with regards to memory use. Streaming the results from a `SqlDataReader` can be done with minimal overhead.

Comment: You are searching every (n)char column of every table. Why? This is not something you want to do frequently and certainly not something you want to do in an application. And if you care about accurate results you should stop using the NOLOCK hint everywhere. It is far more sinister than most people realize. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/